# send btc from specific input without running bitcoind

Tags: raw-transaction, transaction-input, createrawtransaction

Is there any third-party API allowing to send Bitcoins using specific transactions as inputs?

Back in 2013 I had to run bitcoind myself and build a raw transaction manually. But maybe it's easier now, after 3 years? Running bitcoind is not so cheap now, but I really want to forward a bitcoin payment from one address to others, also keeping it safe and clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom transactions to sign using blockcypher's API:

https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/bitcoin/#creating-transactions

You'd have to fiddle with it to get the exact coin control you want, but most of the functionality you're looking for is there if you don't mind the privacy leak.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own very light bitcoin client. It should support `version` and `tx` messages: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation

So, you make TCP connection to any bitcoin node with white IP. You can choose blockchain.info, for example. Your light client sends `version` message, remote node sends you `getdata` message, and you send back your transaction in `tx` message. After that remote node verifies it and spreads to other nodes, and to entire network.

You don't have to care about safety. Noone can steal your bitcoins if you correctly generated raw transaction.

Comment: And maybe a thin bitcoin client exists that would provide a 'createrawtransaction' or similar functionality? I tried searching and didn't find any API of the currently available thin clients though, but maybe I didn't search well enough.

Comment: You can check libbitcoin-explorer https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Libbitcoin_Explorer It doesn't download all 80GB+ data. You can create transactions here: https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-explorer/wiki/bx-tx-encode Add send them: https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-explorer/wiki/bx-send-tx